# Can a HTML button perform a POST request?

Tags: javascript, html, post, button, submit

I want a submit type button to send a POST request.

I am thinking about something like this:

```
<form action = "" method = "post">
    <button>Upvote</button>
<form>
```

where the string "Upvote" will be send as a name in the POST request.

I know this is not working, and I know there are ways using AJAX(javascript) but I am fairly new to this area. I am just wondering if this is possible in general.

**Update**

Someone suggested using the `<input>` tag, and I tried it. The problem is it generates a GET rather than a POST.

Comment: It wont post the upvote string to the server I believe. I will try now

Comment: you need js support such as jquery $.post

Comment: you can use some js to call submit from the form.

Comment: you need to make use of the submit button: `<button type="submit">Send it</button>` the rest of your code looks good (except the spaces), the action field holds the url to the desired server resource, which takes the data for further processing.

Comment: You really need to take the time to familiarize yourself with [HTML Forms](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html).

Comment: @Oded Anyone used to be a newbie before he becomes a pro, I am leraning it.

Comment: Of course. And I am pointing you to a great learning resource.

Answer (score 78, accepted):

This can be done with an input element of a type "submit". This will appear as a button to the user and clicking the button will send the form.

```
<form action="" method="post">
    <input type="submit" name="upvote" value="Upvote" />
</form>
```

Answer (score 99):

You need to give the button a name and a value.

No control can be submitted without a name, and the content of a button element is the label, not the value.

```
<form action="" method="post">
    <button name="foo" value="upvote">Upvote</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Is it ok (cross-browsers safe) to use this button without `type="submit"`?

Comment: @MohammedNoureldin — Yes, it is. `submit` is the default value for the `type` attribute on a `<button>`

Comment: Is it possible to capture the response to communicate to the user if the post request was successful or not? With just HTML?

Answer (score 26):

You can do that with a little help of JS.
In the example below, a POST request is being submitted on a button click using the fetch method:

```js
const button = document.getElementById('post-btn');

button.addEventListener('click', async _ => {
  try {     
    const response = await fetch('yourUrl', {
      method: 'post',
      body: {
        // Your body
      }
    });
    console.log('Completed!', response);
  } catch(err) {
    console.error(`Error: ${err}`);
  }
});
```

```html
<button id="post-btn">I'm a button</button>
```

Comment: failed to fetch?

Comment: how can I include Headers in this? Just add a 'headers' section in the 'await' function?

Answer (score 5):

Simply do:

```
<form action="" method="post" id="myForm">
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-sm btn-info" name="something"><i class="fa fa-check"></i>Submit</button>
</form>
```

Or in the case that for aesthetic reasons you want the button outside the form, do:

```
<button type="submit" form="myForm" class="btn btn-sm btn-info" name="something"><i class="fa fa-check"></i>Submit</button>
```

I typically use this when my form is too long and I want a submit button at the beginning and also at the end of the page.

Comment: This sends a POST variable `something` with an empty string (`""`) as its contents. You can use this without setting the value attribute, to get which button was clicked e.g. in PHP, you would test `if(isset($_POST["someting"]))`.

Answer (score 4):

You can:

- Either, use an `<input type="submit" ..>`, instead of that button.
- or, Use a bit of javascript, to get a hold of form object (using name or id), and call `submit(..)` on it. Eg: `form.submit()`. Attach this code to the button click event. This will serialise the form parameters and execute a GET or POST request as specified in the form's method attribute.

Comment: using <input> ... will generate a GET request rather than POST... I've test it

Comment: ```<form action = "" method "post">
  <input type="Submit" name="upvote" value="Upvote"/>
 </form>``` The code I have

Comment: @dorafmon — Unless the form was rendered at the URL `http://127.0.0.1:8000/debate/00000001?upvote=Upvote` in the first place, you should not get that result.

Comment: I started with ```debate/00000001``` first, then click the upvote button and then I get the result url...

Comment: I really suspect some other part of your page is modifying the method attribute, then.