# Use POST method to display data from database PHP

Tags: php, html, post

I am using this SQL query in a link to retrieve data from database

```
<div class="nav-laptop"><a href="proizvodi.php?upit=SELECT Slika, Naziv, Opis, Cijena FROM Proizvodi WHERE Kategorija='Laptop' ORDER BY Proizvodac Asc;">Laptop</a>
```

and display it using

```
$sql = $_REQUEST['upit'];

$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    echo "<div class='proizvodi'>";
    // output data of each row
     $result->data_seek(0);
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        echo "<div class='row'>";
            foreach($row as $key => $value){
                echo "<div class='" . $key . "'>" . $value . "</div>";
            }
        echo "</div>";
        echo "<hr />";
    }
    echo "</div>";
}
else {
    echo "<div class='search-query-none'><img src='index/no result.png' width='754' height='198' /></div>";
}
```

I realized this is very vulnerable and that I should use POST method to hide parameters from URL. I tried reading online forums, but I found nothing that would help me to convert this to POST way of retrieving data.
So, how do I use POST method to achieve the same result as I am achieving right now using GET?

Comment: you would have to use a form (easiest way) to send parameters via POST method. Only send the parameters that might change - like the category in your case. And then use prepared statements to not be vulnerable.

Comment: You should build the query in PHP. Sending queries from the URL is very insecure. If someone found this and loaded `proizvodi.php?upit=delete from Proizvodi` your whole data's table is gone; or possible worse changed all the text to links.

Comment: Take a look at, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16036041/can-a-html-button-preform-a-post-request and/or https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Forms/Sending_and_retrieving_form_data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will give you a general idea on how to do this.

HTML form:

```
<form method="post" action="your_handler.php">
   <input type = "text" name = "search_query">
   <input type = "submit" name = "submit" value = "Search">
</form>
```

SQL/PHP and assuming a successful connection using the [MySQLi API](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysqli-connect.php).

```
$conn = mysqli_connect("your_host", "user", "password", "db");

if (!$conn) {
    echo "Error: Unable to connect to MySQL." . PHP_EOL;
    echo "Debugging errno: " . mysqli_connect_errno() . PHP_EOL;
    echo "Debugging error: " . mysqli_connect_error() . PHP_EOL;
    exit;
}

if(isset($_POST['submit'])){

    if(!empty($_POST['search_query'])){

    $search_query = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['search_query']);

    $result = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE col = '$search_query' ");

    if(!$result) { echo "Error: " . mysqli_error($conn); }

    if ($result->num_rows > 0) {

            while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
                // perform what you want here
                // and check for errors on your query
            }

        }
    }

}
```

You can substitute `SELECT *` with the said columns also.

Ideally, a prepared statement is nice to work with.

- http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php
- http://php.net/pdo.prepared-statements (if you want to look into PDO).

Sidenote: Do not intermix different MySQL APIs such as `mysqli_` with PDO. They just don't mix together.

Check for errors also against your query:

- http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php

Add `or die(mysqli_error($conn))` to `mysqli_query()`.

Add [**error reporting**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php) to the top of your file(s) which will help find errors.

```
<?php 
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);

// Then the rest of your code
```

**Sidenote:** Displaying errors should only be done in staging, and never production.

Plus, make sure that no whitespace gets introduced into your input, otherwise your query may fail.

- Use [`trim()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.trim.php) against the input.

Comment: Wow, this looks nice. I will take a look into it.

Comment: @BloodDrunk Enjoy! ;-) *Cheers*

Comment: Thank you so much!
I was having troubles with it last night, and now I managed to make it work finally. Hopefully this is much more safe from SQL injection now than it was before (definitely..): I've got hella lot to learn.

Comment: @BloodDrunk You're most welcome, glad I could be of help, *cheers!*

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to use `POST` for a `SELECT` query. You *can*, but it's really better suited for `INSERT / UPDATE / DELETE`, things that actually change your data. A possible advantage to using a link like that for search results is that it can be saved, bookmarked, emailed, etc., where a form submission cannot. But you are right that putting your entire query into a link like that definitely is *extremely* vulnerable.

Instead of passing the entire query through the link, you can just pass the parameters, like this:

```
<a href="proizvodi.php?kategorija=Laptop">Laptop</a>
```

Then in your display code you can use a prepared statement and safely bind the parameter:

```
$kategorija = $_GET['kategorija'];

$sql = 'SELECT Slika, Naziv, Opis, Cijena FROM Proizvodi 
        WHERE Kategorija=? ORDER BY Proizvodac';

$stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
$stmt->bind_param("s", $kategorija);
$stmt->execute();
// etc.
```

Comment: I tried using this, but it return no result hm. Probably query error.