# python code using web servers and buttons?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I need help with writing code on python using web servers. I want to know when a button is clicked how to tell a LED to be turned on and to relay that information back to the web server displaying if the LED is on or off.
Here is my current code.
    import web

```
global status
status = [0]

render = web.template.render('web/')

urls = ( '/', 'hello')
app = web.application(urls, globals(), True)

class hello:
    def GET(self):
        getInput = web.input(turn="")
        command = str(getInput.turn)

        return """<html>
<head>
<title>Control Centre  </title>
</head>
<body>
<font size="20"> </font>
<p> <font size="20">  <b>Control  Centre</b> </font>  </p>
</body>
<p> <button type="submit1">LED 1</button> </p>
<p> <button type="submit2">LED 2</button> </p>
<p> <button type="submit3">LED 3</button> </p>
<p> <button type="submit4">LED 4</button> </p>
<p> <button type="submit5">LED 5</button> </p>
<p> <button type="submit6">LED 6</button> </p>
<p> <button type="submit7">BUZZER</button> </p>
</html>"""
         if command == "1":
                if status[0] == 0:
                    status[0] = 1
                    GPIO.output(4, GPIO.HIGH)
                    print 'LED 1 ON'
                    return render.index(status)
                elif status[0] == 1:
                    status[0] = 0
                    GPIO.output(4, GPIO.LOW)
                    print 'LED 1 OFF'
                    return render.index(status)
                else:
                    print 'error'
                    return render.index(status)
                return render.index(status)






if __name__ == "__main__":
        app.run()
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16036041/can-a-html-button-perform-a-post-request

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One of possible solutions is as follows:

- Wrap a button in a `<form>` tag with `POST` as an action like ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16036041/can-a-html-button-preform-a-post-request))
- Implement a POST handler on your server (`do_POST`) that will perform required logic on LED

**Update:**

Here are some more explanations:

In the server code above you have implemented a so-called `GET` handler, a function that is being called when server receives an [HTTP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypertext_Transfer_Protocol) request made via [HTTP method (verb) `GET`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypertext_Transfer_Protocol#Request_methods). When a `GET` request is sent by some client application (for example a browser, when user navigates to the address of the server), upon receiving it, server's internals call your `GET()` function and execute its body. Your function returns the HTML code string back to the client (and browser receives it, finds the HTML code and renders it as a web page to the user).

Now, in order to send the information *to* the server, you need client to send an HTTP request via [HTTP method (verb) `POST`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/POST_(HTTP)) to the server. For instance, that is what a [`<button>`](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_button.asp) inside a [`<form>`](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_form.asp) does when user clicks it in a browser. Sure enough, you want your web server to be able to receive and handle this `POST` request, performing some useful action. It is typically done by implementing a `POST` handler function. Check your [HTTP server package's documentation](http://webpy.org/docs/0.3/tutorial) for details on how to make so. I guess you will need to create a function called `POST()` and to put whatever logic you want to be executed inside it.

References:

- [Hypertext Transfer Protocol (Wiki)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypertext_Transfer_Protocol)
- [POST (HTTP) (Wiki)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/POST_(HTTP))
- [HTTP Methods (Mozilla Developers)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Methods)
- [`<button>` HTML tag (w3schools.com)](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_button.asp)
- [`<form>` HTML tag (w3schools.com)](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_form.asp)
- [Webpy documentation](http://webpy.org/docs/0.3/tutorial)

Comment: What do you mean implement a POST handler, could you explain more?

Comment: @Pewis I've added some more detailed explanation in the answer body.