# Run node.js app from html by pressing a button

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, telegram-bot, node-telegram-bot-api

I made a telegram bot in node js and I would like to be able to start it by pressing a button from an html page, how can I do it? also I would like that even after the web page is closed, the bot continues to work.

To run the bot from the console I use the command: `node bot.js`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way will be: Creating a server in nodejs and post the request from the html button.

STEP 1: Create html from for sending request to server:
[Can a html button perform a POST request?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16036041/can-a-html-button-perform-a-post-request)

STEP 2: Create the server for receiving the request and do the work:
[How is an HTTP POST request made in node.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6158933/how-is-an-http-post-request-made-in-node-js)

Comment: So I should make a node.js server that through the POST request made by html can start the bot?

Comment: Yes exactly. with this command **node bot.js** you will run the server, and the code of the bot can be in this bot.js file. so when post request called you will run the code of bot.

Comment: Thanks, for now I think it's the best solution, I'll try.